# Create seq of maps from two lists with specified keys

Tags: scala

I have two lists, one containing string elements and the other containing int elements, say 
`foo = ["In", "Out"]` and `bar = [10, 6]`.

I want to create a sequence of maps which maps `foo` elements to "Key" and `bar` elements to "Value" such that

```
Seq(Map("Key" -> "In", "Value" -> 10), Map("Key" -> "Out", "Value" -> 6))
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: That may be what you want, but it's not a good idea. Try retrieving one of the `"Value"` values and adding `1` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` both the lists and then map over the combined list to create desired `Seq`

```
val lst = List("In", "Out")
val lst2 = List(10, 6)
lst.zip(lst2).map(x=> Map("key" -> x._1,"value"-> x._2))

//output
//List(Map(key -> In, value -> 10), Map(key -> Out, value -> 6))
```

Comment: You can also use `map{ case (k, v) => Map("Key" -> k, "Value" -> v) }` which is a bit more verbose but perhaps a bit clearer.

Comment: I would use for-comprehension `for ((k, v) ← lst zip lst2) yield Map("key" -> k, "value" -> v)`.